# How to send mail from WAMP server using PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, wampserver

i have tried to send mail from WAMP server but still its not working...
can anyone tell me the whole step to be followed to send mail from WAMP server.note:i am using (7.0.4) version of WAMP server.

Comment: have you tried phpMailer?

Comment: To send a mail you need a mail server instead of web server..

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` function wont work by default for WAMP. You will need to add details of your SMTP server in the php.ini file.

```
SMTP = ; Enter here the address of your SMTP server
smtp_port = 25
```

Then you can use your own PHP code or use third party libraries like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or many other open source libraries, which you can find by simple search.